# Branch LiveView Shows links triggering on page load

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

In liveview > links, deeplinks are showing up whenever I land on a page. I would expect them to only show up on click. Is this generic behavior?

Edit: This also seems to only be happening with UTM parameters.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Liveview Events](http://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/events), select from the dropdown the event that you would like to see(e.g. CLICK or INSTALL or OPEN). The [Liveview > Links](http://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/links) show only the live data of link creation.

Refer to this document for more: https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/pba-liveview/#liveview. For any further questions, please reach out to integrations@branch.io.